# MySQL Error Code: 3819. Check constraint '...' is violated

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an Error because of the Check Constraint and i dont know why.

```
create table TStudenten (
StudId int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
StudVorname varchar(25) not null,
StudNachname varchar(25) not null,
StudStrasse varchar(40),
StudPLZ char(4),
StudOrt varchar(20),
StudGebDatum date,
StudEmail varchar(30) not null,
constraint GebDatumCheck check ('2023-01-01' - StudGebDatum > 18));
```

And then i insert Data in it

```
insert into TStudenten values (null, 'Werner', 'Döbele', 'Bergstrasse 15', '8278', 'Pfyn', '1974-09-13', 'Werner.Doebele@hotmail.com');
```

And i get a Error Code: 'Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'GebDatumCheck' is violated.'

I tried without the Check and then it worked but i need the Check.

Comment: I doubt if hard coding the date in the constraint is a good idea - what happens in 2024,2025..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `constraint check` you are looking for something to allow only dates from the last 18 years.

Try this instead :

```
constraint GebDatumCheck check (YEAR('2023-01-01') - YEAR(StudGebDatum) > 18));
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8iU5O7c)

Answer (score 0):

`'2023-01-01' - StudGebDatum > 18`
means that you compare the date difference to 18 days not years.

You can use `DATE_SUB('2023-01-01', INTERVAL 18 YEAR)` or simply `'2005-01-01'` for comparison instead.